# What are types finishing with "N" in Sybase ASE?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sqldatatypes, sybase-ase15

I'm working with a Sybase ASE 15.7 instance.

After querying the `systypes` table, I've seen many data types such as `floatn`, `intn`, `datetimn`, `moneyn`. They have the same length of their counterparts (`float`, `int`, `datetime`, ...) and seem to differ only in its type code and hierarchy. Sybase ASE documentation mention the former (as in [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1572/html/tables/X37714.htm) or [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1550/html/blocks/blocks13.htm)) but there is no explanation of their purpose.

What are these data types intended for and what's the difference with their counterparts without the trailing "N"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user designates a column as a fixed-length column **AND** nullable, ASE will silently convert this datatype to a variable-length/nullable datatype designated as `<datatype>n`.

When you run `sp_help` you should still see the original datatype, but internally ASE will use the `<datatype>n` type.

You can read a bit more about this in the ASE documentation on [Datatype Conversions](https://help.sap.com/viewer/2df920cd5b1644e5a065d55b637d5e92/16.0.3.5/en-US/aac4f65ebc2b1014b6ae81582f7c1bf7.html)